# Вопрос по учебному заданию

Tags: sql

читаю и пытаюсь на ходу решать задачи из книги "SQL для простых смертных". Собственно сабж:

> Предположим, каждый продавец имеет 12% комиссионных. Запишите запрос к
>   таблиuе `Orders`, который выдает номер заявки (`order number`), номер продавца
>   (`salesperson number`) и общее значение комиссионных продавца (`amount of
>   salesperson's commission`). Выходные данные упорядочите по значениям последнего столбца.

У меня:

```
SELECT order onum, snum, amt(*.12)
FROM   Orders
Order  by 3;
```

В книге:

```
SELECT onum, snum, amt•.12
FROM   Оrders;
```

Вопрос - почему нет операции по "Выходные данные упорядочите по значениям последнего столбца."

Comment: Возможно просто о печатка в книге?

Comment: вы первый раз в жизни ошибки в книге встречаете что ли?

Comment: Нет не первый но  в силу не владения предметом...